# unique constraint violated?

Tags: java, jdbc

i'm trying to update a table:

```
create table Out_Patient(Patient_ID number(8) primary key ,
First_Name varchar2(20) ,
 Last_Name varchar2(20) ,
Gender varchar2(10) , 
Mobile_Number number(12) ,
 Address varchar2(20),
 Date_Of_Birth Date , 
Date_Of_Entry Date)
```

with foll. code:

```
PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement("Update Out_Patient Set Patient_ID=?,First_Name=?,Last_Name=?,Gender=?,Mobile_Number=?,Address=?,Date_Of_Birth=?,Date_Of_Entry=?");
String t1=text1.getText();
        int id=Integer.parseInt(t1);
        String t2=text2.getText();
        String t3=text3.getText();
        String t4=text4.getText();
        String t5=text5.getText();
        String t6=text_dob.getText();
        String t7=text_doe.getText();
        String s1=combo_gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
             st.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(t1));
         st.setString(2,t2);
         st.setString(3,t3);
        st.setString(4,s1);
        st.setString(5,t5);
        st.setString(6,t4);
        st.setString(7,t6);
        st.setString(8,t7);

            st.executeUpdate();
```

But i'm getting ORA-00001: unique constraint violated.
I know Patient_ID is primary key in table,but while entering details i'm keeping it same as the one in the table.What changes should be made.
Please help!!
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Theres no WHERE clause in your JDBC update statement, therefore you're trying to set the same ID for all records. Take a look at this example: [Creating a PreparedStatement Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#create_ps)

Comment: i even changed to
String t1=text1.getText();
 int id=Integer.parseInt(t1);
 "Update Out_Patient Set First_Name=?,Last_Name=?,Gender=?,Mobile_Number=?,Address=?,Date_Of_Birth=?,Date_Of_Entry=? where Patient_ID=id"
Then i got: Invalid identifier ID

Comment: That's probably because you wrote "where Patient_ID=id", and this "id" identifier is treated as a value, not as a parameter. Try this: "where Patient_ID=?" and in java code assing value for this parameter st.setInt(9,Integer.parseInt(t1));

Comment: i included the where clause where Patient_ID=?

Comment: Have you assigned a value for this parameter?

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it worked..thanks..Just did what you said. 
st.setInt(9,Integer.parseInt(t1));